# How can you possibly use Data Gateway in conjunction with Data Mapper?

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, datamapper, gateway

Well according to Martin Fowler, the table/row data gateway aint mutually exclusive against data mapper pattern. This is what he said:

> These patterns arent entirely mutually exclusive... Even if you are
>   using Data Mapper as your primary persistence mechanism, however, you
>   may use a data gateway to wrap tables or services that are being
>   treated as external interfaces.

However, I cant think of a circumstances when data gateway is being used together with data mapper. Can anyone of you explain this with more details and possibly provide a real example of how integration of data gateway and mapper is done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They aren't mutually exclusive in the sense that you may use both in a single project. Specifically, Fowler indicates that if you have certain tables that are treated as external interfaces, you may encapsulate them with a gateway. A table data gateway is a simple, direct interface. A data mapper on the other hand tends to provide better isolation then a table data gateway and as such is better suited for mapping to a domain model. A primary example of this approach is an ORM.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. So it basically is about simple table/domain logic for Gateway and complex table/domain logic for Data Mapper? I thought the author was saying that you can use gateway as an intermediary to retrieve the raw data, and then the data mapper 'maps' this raw data into domain model.

Comment: Typically in such a scenario, your relational database access library will effectively act as a gateway. In the .NET world that would be ADO.NET, JDBC in Java.